# Probability of a random sample lying between the mean and one standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, means, standard-deviation, percentile

Is this a correct way of calculating the probability $P$ of a randomly selected sample from a distribution lying between the mean $\mu$ and the mean + standard deviation $\mu + \sigma$? Let the inverse percentile be $I^{-1}(x)$ then:

$$ P = I^{-1}(\mu+\sigma) - I^{-1}(\mu) $$

Comment: If by "inverse percentile function" you mean the cumulative distribution function, then, yes, that is correct.

Comment: That works for continuous random variables, though perhaps more common to write $F(\mu+\sigma)-F(\mu)$.  It gets a little more complicated for discrete random variables, requiring a precise meaning for "between"